# AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'select' error ASYNCIO

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am executing the below code on a windows pc. I read that, by default, Windows can use only 64 sockets in asyncio loop. I don't know if this is the reason for the error.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time


async def download_file(url):
    print(f'started downloading{url}')
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=60)
    async with aiohttp.clientSession(connector) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            content = await  resp.read()
            print (f'Finished download{url}')
            return content

async def write_file(n, content):
    filename = f'async_{n}.html'
    with open(filename,'wb') as f:
        print(f'started writing{filename}')
        f.write(content)
        print(f'Finished writing{filename}')

async def scrape_task(n,url):
    content = await download_file(url)
    await write_file(n,content)

async def main():
    tasks = []
    for n,url in enumerate(open('urls.txt').readlines()):
        tasks.append((scrape_task(n, url)))
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t=time.perf_counter()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    t2 = time.perf_counter() - t
    print(f'Total time taken: {t2:0.2f} seconds')
```

I made the below changes to limit the connections to `60`

```
connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=60)
    async with aiohttp.clientSession(connector) as session:
```

I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: I don't see "select" mentioned anywhere in your code sample.  However, the error you are getting is probably not related to a socket limit.

Comment: Error that I am receiving:
  r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'select'

Comment: How did you import the select function?  Also make sure you don't have file named, e.g. `select.py` which may be imported accidentally.

Comment: Please include the error message, including the **full traceback**, in the question. Also, check if you have a file named `select.py` in your current directory and/or the source tree of your project.